# How to fix this: cannot find symbol var in StaticTest

Tags: java

I am trying to compile a code from book about Java and I have a problem with var. I can't compile. What's wrong? 
I have verified and the problem still exists. Can you check this code below?

```
public class StaticTest
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    
        var staff = new Employee[3];

        staff[0] = new Employee("Tomasz", 40000);
        staff[1] = new Employee("Dariusz", 60000);
        staff[2] = new Employee("Grzegorz", 65000);


        for(Employee e : staff)
        {
            e.setId();
            System.out.println("name=" + e.getName() + " ,id=" + e.getId() + " .salary=" + e.getSalary());
        }

        int n = Employee.getNextId();
        System.out.println("Następny dostępny identyfikator=" + n);

    }
}
```

Comment: what version of java (jdk) are you using, and which version is used in the book?

Comment: What Java Compiler Version are you using? `var` was only added in Java 10, so any earliert version will not support it

Comment: @am0awad the question is about the var in the class shown.

Comment: Looks like `e.setId();` is problematic. It should be like `e.setId(1010);`

Comment: I am checking this on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: @tellarwind tutorialspoint is not the most recommended source. but, are you using the same jdk they are using? that is most likely your problem

Comment: @Stultuske - books uses I think Java version 11

Comment: @SudhirOjha based on what? public void setId() { this.id = 5; } is valid Java

Comment: @tellarwind so, are you following a book, or tutorialspoint? and, which jdk are you using? most likely one below java version 10

Comment: @Stultuske Probably you are right because tutorialspoint  uses JDK 1.8.0

Comment: Tutorialspoint seems to support only Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibility to use `var` to declare a variable was added in Java 10.
You have to update your JDK to version 10 or above.
Otherwise you can use `Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];` instead.

Comment: is there no other way to bypass this issue with the lombok.var import?